# How to segregate large real time data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, cron

Let me explain the problem

- We get real time data which is as big as 0.2Million per day.
- Some of these records are of special significance. The attributes
  that shall mark them as significant are pushed in a reference collection.  
   Let us say each row in Master Database has the following attributes

a. ID b. Type c. Event 1 d. Event 2 e. Event 3 f. Event 4

For the special markers, we identify them as

> > Marker1 -- Event 1 -- Value1  
> >     Marker2 -- Event 3 -- Value1  
> >     Marker3 -- Event 1 -- Value2  
> >     and so on. We can add 10000 such markers.

- Further, the attribute Type can be Image, Video, Text, Others. Hence the idea is to segregate Data based on Type, which means that we create 4 collections out of Master Collection. This is because we have to run search on collections based on Type and also run some processing.The marker data should show in a different tab on the search screen.
- We shall also be running a search on Master Collection through a wild search.  
  We are running Crons to do these processes as

I. Dumping Data in Master Collection - Cron 1

II. Assigning Markers - Cron 2

III. Segregating Data based on Type - Cron 3

Which runs as a module. Cron 1 - Cron 2 - Cron 3.

But assigning targets and segregation takes a very long time. We are using Python as scripting language.

In fact, the crons don't seem to work at all. The cron works from the command prompt. But scheduling these in crontab does not work. We are giving absolute path to the files. The crons are scheduled at 3 minutes apart.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also faced this problem but then I tried by moving small chunks of the data. Sharding is not the better way as per my experience regarding this kind of problem. Same thing for the replica set.